# Bulk Create Document sets inside a document library

Tags: document-library, document-set, bulk

I want to create multiple items using power shell in one Document library. This document library has content type as 'document set' so every item created inside this library must be a Document set. Now the question is how can I achieve this using sharepoint powershell.? *pls feel free to share the another way to achieve the same goal.!

Pls help !! urgent

PS:I am working on O365 SharePoint online Site and using "SharePoint Online Management Shell"

Thanks in Advance